# Blackberry: VerticalFieldManager Child Element Not Receiving Focus

Tags: blackberry

I have a `VerticalFieldManger` which is used as container to display a custom news feed.  The idea is an image (`BitmapField`) and a title (`LabelField`) are placed in the `VerticalFieldManager`.

I have subclassed `VerticalFieldManager` for some simple custom elements and their behviours, but I have not overridden any methods declared in the `VerticalFieldManager`.

I would like the `BitmapField` to respond to touch events and navigation clicks to as to open a web browser to display a desired web page.  The issue is that the `VerticalFieldManager` does not receive focus (I did not expect it to), nor do any of the child elements receive focus.

I have not subclassed BitmapField nor LabelField

Constructor for my subclassed VerticalFieldManager:

```
public NewsManagerView( boolean _isClickable, long _style ) {
    super( _style );

    this.setIsClickable( _isClickable );    // sets flag if this should respond to click events

    this.init();    // initialize ivars

    this.add( this.getTitle() );    // add child fields
    this.add( this.getImgFld() );
    this.add( this.getUrl() );
}
```

Which gets instantiated like this:

```
this.setNewsManager( new NewsManagerView(this.getIsConnected(), Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH) );
```

Comment: Can we see some code?  For example, I'm wondering whether you have created your component with the FOCUSABLE style set.

Comment: @Scott W  Which component would that be?

Comment: It depends how customized you want to get.  If you keep the default painting behavior, you will want to set the FOCUSABLE style on the component that you want to look "highlighted" when it is focused.  For example, what happens if you change your instantiation call to pass `Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Field.FOCUSABLE`?

Comment: Both `LabelField` and `BitmapField` are non-focusable by default. I think this is the cause. For instance, if instead of `LabelField` and `BitmapField` you add two `EditField`s - will the issue still exist?

Comment: @Arhimed I added `Field.FOCUSABLE` style bit.  Sadly, I had assumed that something like a BitmapField would receive focus by default, and I did not find anything about it in the BB docs.

Comment: @Mike D: I believe just adding that style bit is not enough. You should also override `isFocusable()` to return `true`.

Comment: @Arhimed  So far, adding the style bit (Field.FOCUSABLE) to the stock BitmapField has solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem.
I started a topic in BB support forum
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Scroll-happening-but-Vertical-Field-Manager-Not-Moving/m-p/1214481

And the answer given was 
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/My-scrollable-manager-is-not-scrolling/ta-p/445247

Sorry that is not a real answer but is the only workaround that's available for the moment

**EDIT:**
In the BB forum a new post added says:

> A friend gave me the solution... you can put your manager into an
>   horizontal manager and then you can just add an nullfield with a
>   focusable behaviour, This will do the trick

You can try that.

Comment: I don't think we can talk about this as about a "known" problem. If childs are non-focusable, then it's obvious that there's nothing that could accept focus. Incomprehension of this is the actual problem.

Comment: The "know" problem is that even being focusable the childs you are not going to be able to set focus on them.

Answer (score 1):

```
VerticalFieldManager datavfm=new VerticalFieldManager(FOCUSABLE)
{
    protected void paintBackground(Graphics graphics) 
    {
        if(!isFocus())
        {
            graphics.setColor( 0xDDDDDD );
            graphics.fillRoundRect( 0, 0, 318, 30, 18, 18);
            graphics.setColor( 0x000000 );
            graphics.drawRoundRect( 0, 0, 318, 30, 18, 18);
            invalidate();
        }
        else
        {
            graphics.setColor( 0x005DE7 );
            graphics.fillRoundRect( 0, 0, 318, 30, 18, 18);
            graphics.setColor( 0xFFFFFF );
            graphics.drawRoundRect( 0, 0, 318, 30, 18, 18);
            graphics.setColor( 0xFFFFFF );
            invalidate();
        }
    }
    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth,int maxHeight)
    {
        super.sublayout(318, 30);
        super.setExtent(318, 30);
    }
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status,int time)
    {
        GetPNRStatus(strPNRNumber);
        return true;
    }
    protected boolean keyChar(char c, int status, int time)
    {
        if (c == Characters.ENTER)
        {
            GetPNRStatus(strPNRNumber);
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```